# Join three tables in mysql but have all data from one table

Tags: mysql, join

I have three tables named book (isbn, name, publisher, price, category, quantity), author (auth_id, auth_name) and written_by(isbn,auth_id). I am joining all three tables but in the result, I want all the books even whose author is not entered in the database. I have written the following query

```
select b.isbn, b.name, b.publisher, b.price, b.category, b.quantity, 
group_concat(a.auth_name) as authors 
from book b 
left outer join written_by w on b.isbn=w.isbn 
left outer join author a on a.auth_id=w.auth_id
group by b.isbn
having  authors like '%';
```

The above query returns only the books who have authors linked to them in the written_by table. I want all the books including the ones with no authors in the database. 
How do I join these three tables in such a way?
EDIT:
Sample Data
Book table
    `isbn    name      publisher    price    category    quantity
 112345  It        New Lib      $10      Horror      2
 234562  The Hob   Puffin       $20      Fiction     5`

Author table
    `auth_id    auth_name
 1          Stephen King
 2          Tolkien`

Written_by table
    `isbn     auth_id
112345    1`

Sample output
`isbn    name      publisher    price    category    quantity    author
 112345  It        New Lib      $10      Horror      2           Stephen King
 234562  The Hob   Puffin       $20      Fiction     5           null`

The above query will return only the book named "It" and will ignore "The Hobbit" since there is no author linked to that book in the written_by table, but I want both the books in the result table with author as null for the book that has no author linked to it

Comment: can you provided a expected sample output example

Answer (score 0):

The below query will select all the books along with the author name, and will be null for those books which are not linked.

```
select b.isbn, b.name, b.publisher, b.price, b.category, b.quantity, 
a.auth_name as authors 
from book b 
left outer join written_by w on b.isbn=w.isbn 
left outer join author a on a.auth_id=w.auth_id
```

is that the one you are looking for?

Comment: Yes your query works, thanks. I just had to remove authors like statement

Answer (score 0):

Just remove this:

`having  authors like '%'`

It should be as following.

```
select b.isbn, b.name, b.publisher, b.price, b.category, b.quantity, 
group_concat(a.auth_name) as authors 
from book b 
left outer join written_by w on b.isbn=w.isbn 
left outer join author a on a.auth_id=w.auth_id
group by b.isbn;
```